# How to check for a device/browser that fully supports the deviceorientation event?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, magnetometer

I have a HTML5 compass that works quite ok. Now I need a smart way to distinguish between "pseudo deviceorientation enabled" browsers (as desktop chrome and FF) and real candidates like iPhone/Android/iPad Browsers that use the device's magnetometor.

My current solution is a basic check for the DeviceOrientationEvent and touch support:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent && 'ontouchstart' in window) {
  // setup real compass thing, with event.alpha
} else {
  // setup some mouse following hack
}
```

Is that enough? I'm not really sure about devices "with touch support but no magnetometer", as for example chrome on a mac book has touch support, and a fake deviceorientation?

Comment: if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert("Landscape Orientation!");
}

also you can refer to [this url](http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change)

Comment: for testing touch support you can use

function is_touch_device() {  
  try {  
    document.createEvent("TouchEvent");  
    return true;  
  } catch (e) {  
    return false;  
  }  
}

Comment: thx, but it's not about orientation change. it's about "does it have a real compass built in". see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation the example at the bottom works in my chrome on mac book...

Comment: What has 'ontouchstart' to do with deviceorientation?

Comment: Poor try to somehow check if a device might have a real compass built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems to work as is, I was wrong, chrome on mac book is not going into the "real compass" section. should have tested it, maybe.

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent && 'ontouchstart' in window) {
    // setup real compass thing, with event.alpha
    document.body.innerHTML = "haz!";
} else {
    // setup some mouse following hack
    document.body.innerHTML = "nope";
}
```

check yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/benzkji/J58ef/

remains what happens if a touch enabled windos laptop with deviceorientation enabled chrome is showing up. probably check the "absolute" property of the deviceorientation event: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: and probably use modernizr, for a more sane touch capability detection.