# DeviceOrientationEvent not working on all servers

Tags: javascript, server, device-orientation

I have fedora installed on a virtual machine on my computer, and I've been trying to get deviceOrientation events to fire when I view the site on my phone.

It hasn't been working, so using the answer from this thread: [How to check for a device/browser that fully supports the deviceorientation event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892719/how-to-check-for-a-device-browser-that-fully-supports-the-deviceorientation-even), I ran this code to check if it's supported:

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent && 'ontouchstart' in window) {
    // setup real compass thing, with event.alpha
    document.write("haz!");
} else {
    // setup some mouse following hack
    document.write("nope");
}
```

This results in "nope". But I know that my phone supports deviceOrientation, because the example on MDN works.

Then, I uploaded the **exact same** file to my own website, where lo and behold, it gave me "haz!".

I have no idea why the server I use should make a difference to whether deviceOrientation is supported. The only thing I can think of is that maybe it requires SSL, but I don't see SSL mentioned anywhere in any documentation, and I have previously used deviceOrientation on a website hosted on my raspberry pi, which didn't have SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From v.76 Chrome requires that the page you are on is served through `https`.

This can be seen by going to this [`http://` fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujea8g2z/) which will output `nope`, while the same fiddle [served through `https://`](https://jsfiddle.net/ujea8g2z/) will output `haz!`, just like the snippet below, which is served through `https:`

```js
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    console.log("haz!");
} else {
    console.log("nope");
}
```

[Here is the chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=932078&can=1&q=motion%20event%20secure&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) that introduced this restriction.

Note that if it is only for your own purpose, then you can leverage it by starting your Chrome with the [`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure), apparently [it's also possible to do it on mobile versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280796/run-google-chrome-with-flags-on-android) (though I didn't test myself).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy with that haha. Any idea why they've disabled it without SSL? What security risk could deviceOrientation pose?

Comment: It's actually per specs recommendations: https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/#security-and-privacy Their point is that it's a wonderful way to finger-print users since two different hardwares will produce different precision. (btw I found the crbug that introduced this change and added it in my answer)